How to create a group that has at least 3 unique values in one column and 4 unique variations in another column in Bigquery
I have a table and when aligned by time I would like to create a group - starting with group 1 and starting with the most recent result every row is marked as group 1 until there are (e.g) 4 unique values from column A and 3 unique values from column B. Once the criteria is met then group 2 is started with the same criteria but the values do not have to be distinct from group 1 i.e. if value 'y' is in group 1 it also counts as a distinct value in group 2 etc.



Time
Property A (need 4 variations)
Property B (needs 3 variations)
Group (Desired Outcome)




0.499305555555556
a
x
1


0.540972222222222
b
y
1


0.582638888888889
c
x
1


0.624305555555556
a
x
1


0.665972222222222
c
v
1


0.707638888888889
f
z
1


0.749305555555556
d
w
2


0.790972222222223
a
w
2


0.83263888888889
d
x
2


0.874305555555557
g
x
2


0.915972222222224
s
x
2


0.957638888888891
d
x
2


0.999305555555558
h
v
2


1.04097222222223
y
z



1.08263888888889
u
w



1.12430555555556
s
x




